# React-Native: "FirebaseError: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)"

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building a React Native app, currently trying to implement an authentication registration system through Firebase Auth. I've followed a guide/the docs on the website to setup the Firebase config file. I run the app, enter a email and password, when I click the signup button I'm given the follow error below:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
```

I've search on google for possible fixes yet nothing seems to work. I've initialized Firebase as per the docs/tutorials I've watched. Hopefully someone can shed some light on the matter. I'll include the config file code below, XXXX to replace my actual config info

**firebase.js**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXX",
  projectId: "XXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXX",
  appId: "XXXX",
  measurementId: "XXXX"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

**api.js**

```
export function registerUser({email, password}) {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

**EDIT/ANSWER**

As helped in the comments below, the correct way was to implement/import through React-Native-Firebase. Links are in the comments.

Comment: you are using react-native-firebase package? by invertase?

Comment: if you are using react-native-firebase you are not in need to use the config ! you will have to put the json file,plist file in native part of the project! and for Auth you have to install the firebase/auth too!

Comment: The guide I went off just used firebase as shown in the code above. It used the web setup through Firebase console instead of Android/iOS

Comment: import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth";

it will not work if you used  FIrebase (JS package from npm) .   

if you want the firebase to work better on RN apps go with React-native-firebase

Comment: Ah okay. So just 'npm i react-native-firebase' and thats it? Or do I have to do the configuration as well in the android build.gradle files as well?

Comment: you have to do the configs

Comment: So once the Firebase project is made and you choose to implement through iOS/Android/Web which do you do? I tried Android before but it just casued a lot of errors with the gradle build as I code through VSCode, I'd have to then open project on Android Studio to try sync the gradle? This time I was trying with the Web option

Comment: i do for android, iOS,  make the config files and save them in native code.!   yeah I am do work with VSCODE <3

Comment: Okay I'll give it a shot. Sorry for your troubles, could you confirm this is the correct docs guide to do the Android side? Thankyou very much
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android

Comment: https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/ .  use this

Comment: @Rizwanatta  Sorry for delay, I finally got around to it. Invertase works! Thankyou very much! Would you be able to upvote my question so I can gain reputation to upvote others posts with correct answers in the future please :)

Comment: accept the answer of mine as it helped

Comment: for more please reachout anytime

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203966/react-native

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seemingly you are using the syntax of Invertase Firebase project while on the back you are using the WEB SDK of firebase from a firebase npm package.

here is what you  should do:

go and install react-native-firebase from [here](https://rnfirebase.io)

make sure the pods work and auto-linking works,   you have included the json and plist file.! only following these your projects will build and you can use the syntax you have posted in your question!

Answer (score 2):

I think need to put below setup in AppDelegate.m file ...

```
 #import <Firebase.h>
  
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
      [FIRApp configure];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Android:
On rn71 stock templates if you use google-services 4.4.0 it fails on android .

If you use rn71 you must use google-services 4.3.15 - it works fine
If you use rn72 you may update to google-services 4.4.0 - it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You Write Your configuration Like Follow:

```
componetWillMount() {
const config = {
apiKey: “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”,
authDomain: “auth-bdcdc.firebaseapp.com 20”,
databaseURL: “https://auth-bdcdc.firebaseio.com 7”,
projectId: “auth-bdcdc”,
storageBucket: “auth-bdcdc.appspot.com 2”,
messagingSenderId: “xxxxxxxxxx”
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if **GoogleService-Info.plist** is missing in the ios folder.